# Interactive slider in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have created a slider in Javascript but I want to now change it to an interactive slider where you click on it to change slides and not just automatic.  I have changed the javascript and now when I click on a slide it comes up with page not found.  What have I forgotten to do.  This is what I have so far.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
            slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
            slideimages[0].src = "Photos/slide1.jpg" // set image object src property to an image's src, preloading that image in the process
            slideimages[1] = new Image()
            slideimages[1].src = "Photos/slide2.jpg"
            slideimages[2] = new Image()
            slideimages[2].src = "photos/slide3.jpg"
    </script>   
</head> 
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <img id="logo" src="Photos/logo.jpg"  alt="My logo">
        </div>
    <div id="navigation_container">
 <!-- the body -->
        <div class="rectangle">
 <!-- the navigation links -->
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&#10029; link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
 <!-- end the body -->
        </div>
 <!-- end container -->
    </div>
    </header>
        <div id="content-scroll">
          <h1> Scrapbooking ideas</h1>
          <a href="javascript:slidelink()"><img src="Photos/slide1.jpg" id="slide" width=550 height=300 /></a>

          <script type="text/javascript">

            //variable that will increment through the images
            var step = 0
            var whichimage = 0

            function slideit(){
              //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
              if (!document.images)
                return
              document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
              whichimage = step
              if (step<2)
                step++
              else
                step=0
              //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
              setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
            }

            function slidelink(){
              if (whichimage == 0)
                window.location = "link1.htm"
              else if (whichimage == 1)
                window.location = "link2.htm"
              else if (whichimage == 2)
                window.location = "link3.htm"
            }

            slideit()

          </script>
```

Thanks for any help
Linda

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even use any sort of `<a>` tag here. I'd apply the `onclick` attribute suggested by sanfor directly to the `<img>` tag, so your code would be:

`<img src="Photos/slide1.jpg" id="slide" width="550" height="300" />`

Note that I used double quotes when I put in values for the `width` and `height` attributes. This is just a good practice to do. Both ways of going about it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if i get it right, you want something like this.

for automatically start if user doesn't click on any of the links you can start automatically after 10 seconds using this piece of code

```
 setTimeout(function(){slideit(0);},10000);
```

or user can click any of the links to start sliding with specific image associated with it before 10 seconds have passed(you can give it any specific time)

```
setTimeout(function(){slideit(0);},10000);

             var links=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
           for(i=1;i<links.length;i++){
                  (function(val){
                      links[val].addEventListener('click',function(){
                         slideit(val);
                      });

                  })(i);

           }

            //variable that will increment through the images
            var step = 0;
            var whichimage = 0;

            function slideit(num){
              //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
              if (!document.images)
                return
              document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[num].src;

              if (num<2)
                num++;
              else
                num=0;
              //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
              setTimeout("slideit("+num+")",2500)
            }
```